# Only one side of .wrl models gets rendered in ThreeJs

Tags: javascript, three.js, vrml

I have a `.wrl` file that looks normal (image below) when opened in MeshLab or Microsoft 3D Builder. However when loaded with Threejs `THREE.VRMLLoader` only one side of it gets rendered. I'm using the sample code from the three.js developers site.

```
var loader = new THREE.VRMLLoader();
loader.load( filename, function ( object ) {

        scene.add( object );

});
```

[model opened in MeshLab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBTwk.png)

[model loaded in ThreeJs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yencH.png)

Comment: as an option, read [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44233132/4045502)

Comment: iterating through the loaded object and setting the `material.side = THREE.DoubleSide` of the child meshes solved the issue. Thank you for the tip.